# Android Custom Listview, ID of Object Repeats After Scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

I have been given an app to develop based on "ORDER MANAGEMENT", I am developing the most basic task of this app, which is "List of items with ORDER Button, when button is clicked, a dialog appears with the item title which asks a user to enter quantity of item which is to be ordered." Now I am listing which tasks is completed."
Displaying List of Items.
Each Item contains ORDER BUTTON with it, which is clicked to show a dilog. It   also works, Dialog asks for Quantity using Edittext, on confirming dialog action I am also getting the value of edittext as a string and saving it in a variable.
Now the problem I am facing is when I click on the second last and last item in the listview, it returns me the id of first and second item respectively, i.e. 1 and 2. ID's should be what I have assigned in making datalist. I know that there is some problem in my adapter, but I cannot resolve it.

Here is item class Item.java

```
package com.example.learnone;

public class Item {

    private String name,partnumber,description;
    private double price,cost;
    private int id, qtyStart,qtySold,qtyPerPack,qtyordered;

    public Item(){}

    public Item(int id, double price, String name, int qtyordered){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.qtyordered = qtyordered;
    }

    public Item(double price, String name, int qtyordered){
        super();
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.qtyordered = qtyordered;
    }   

    public Item(String name){
        super();
        this.name = name;       
    }

    public int getQtyordered() {
        return qtyordered;
    }

    public void setQtyordered(int qtyordered) {
        this.qtyordered = qtyordered;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPartnumber() {
        return partnumber;
    }

    public void setPartnumber(String partnumber) {
        this.partnumber = partnumber;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public int getQtyStart() {
        return qtyStart;
    }

    public void setQtyStart(int qtyStart) {
        this.qtyStart = qtyStart;
    }

    public int getQtySold() {
        return qtySold;
    }

    public void setQtySold(int qtySold) {
        this.qtySold = qtySold;
    }

    public int getQtyPerPack() {
        return qtyPerPack;
    }

    public void setQtyPerPack(int qtyPerPack) {
        this.qtyPerPack = qtyPerPack;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Here is AdapterItem.java

```
public class AdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    Context context;
    List<Item> itemList;
    int layoutResID;
    int[] quantity;

    public AdapterItem(Context context, int resource,
            List<Item> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = objects;
        this.layoutResID = resource;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView viewItemName,viewItemPrice,viewItemQuantity;
        Button viewQuantityAdder;
        int pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final Item item = getItem(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            final LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);

            holder.viewItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.viewItemPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
            holder.viewItemQuantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
            holder.viewQuantityAdder = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_adder);
            holder.viewQuantityAdder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), item.getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                    builder.setTitle(item.getName().toString());

                    final View dialogView = View.inflate(getContext(),R.layout.dialog_quantity, null);

                    builder.setView(dialogView)

                   .setPositiveButton("TO CART", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           EditText newQuantity = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.takeQuantity);
                           item.setQtyordered(Integer.parseInt(newQuantity.getText().toString()));
                           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ID: " + Integer.toString(item.getId()) + " Quantity: " +Integer.parseInt(newQuantity.getText().toString()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           //Toast.makeText(getContext(), Integer.toString(item.getQtyordered()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           //notifyDataSetChanged();
                       }
                   })

                   .setNeutralButton("RESET", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   })

                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   }
                               });  

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();                                  
                }

            });

            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        holder.viewItemName.setText(item.getName());
        holder.viewItemPrice.setText(Integer.toString(item.getId()));
        holder.viewItemQuantity.setText("QUANTITY: " + Integer.toString(item.getQtyordered()));     

        return view;
    }

}
```

And this is a MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    FragmentItemList fragmentItemList;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentItemList = new FragmentItemList();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentItemList);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();       

    }

    public static class FragmentItemList extends Fragment{

        ProgressBar pb;

        List<Item> dataList;

        public FragmentItemList() {
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState){

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items_list, container, false);

                pb = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

                ListView itemListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemListView);

                /*
                List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();                                            
                testList.add("Sprocket Kit");
                testList.add("Engine Bolt Kit");

                ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testList);
                itemListView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
                */

                dataList = new ArrayList<Item>();

                dataList.add(new Item(1, 40.0, "SPROCKETS BOLTS KIT", 0));
                dataList.add(new Item(2, 190.0, "ENGINE BOLTS KIT", 0));
                dataList.add(new Item(3, 25.0, "ENGINE AXEL KIT", 0));
                dataList.add(new Item(4, 4.0, "LONG CAP SHOW NUT", 0));
                dataList.add(new Item(5, 2.5, "CAP NUT", 0));
                dataList.add(new Item(6, 0.75, "WELD NUTS M6", 0));
                dataList.add(new Item(7, 1.10, "WELD NUTS M8", 0));

                AdapterItem itemsAdapter = 
                        new AdapterItem(getActivity(), R.layout.item_row, dataList);
                itemListView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

I am looking for good suggestions and guide.
Thanks.

Comment: When you say "it returns me the id of first and second item respectively",  in which step of the process are they returned? After entering the amount in the edit text?

Comment: Yes. When I enter amount and I am toasting it. It displays id 1 and 2 for the last two items respectively.